# Encrypt file with FileReader

Tags: java, encryption, filereader

In my java program I would like to read a .txt file in and encode it afterwards. I know how to read a File in and tried to learn how to encode an array. The problem I have is that I don't know how to combine it, it doesn't work the way I tried it.

Here's the part I can read in my text file with:

```
public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
      {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String zeile = "";

        do
        {
          zeile = br.readLine();
          System.out.println(zeile);
        }
        while (zeile != null);

        br.close();
     }
}
```

In this part I can encrypt and decrypt bytes:

```
public class Crypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{
            KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
            SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();

            Cipher desalgCipher;
            desalgCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");


            byte[] text = "test".getBytes("UTF8");


            desalgCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
            byte[] textEncrypted = desalgCipher.doFinal(text);

            String s = new String(textEncrypted);
            System.out.println(s);

            desalgCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
            byte[] textDecrypted = desalgCipher.doFinal(textEncrypted);

            s = new String(textDecrypted);
            System.out.println(s);
        }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
    }

}
```

I thought to read the text file in and put it in a string to encode it, but I think it is way too complex. Is there another way to connect them, or is another way for encoding required?

Comment: You should look a bit at streams (`FileInputStream`, `CipherOutputStream` might be the most useful for you)

Comment: Read the to string, change string to byte array, encrypt bytes...

Comment: @JeremyGrand what's the difference to the FileReader? Doesn't the FileInputStream just read it in as well?

Comment: The fileReader is wrapping a (File)InputStream in order to parse char from bytes. It's counter-productive to parse bytes into chars to then convert them back into bytes. You can open a `FileInputStream` directly on your file, wrap it with a `CipherInputStream` that will encrypt every byte read on the fly and then wrap it again with a `Reader`. That's a more proper way to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly advise you to use `Stream`s ( see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html & https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) rather than directly using a `FileReader`.

Encryption happens at a lower level (on bytes) than what you're trying to do.
Java ciphers offer the convenient `CipherInputStream` (and `CipherOutputStream` ) to encrypt byte streams on the fly. It's much cheaper and more scalable than trying to dump a whole file in a single `byte[]` (moreso because you're decoding and re-encoding the file content).

If you want an example of use, please look at the following snippet :

```
public static void encrypt(Path inputFile, OutputStream output) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
    // init cipher
    KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
    SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();
    Cipher desalgCipher;
    desalgCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    desalgCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);


    try(InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(inputFile);        // get an IS on your file
    CipherInputStream cipherIS = new CipherInputStream(is, desalgCipher)){   // wraps input Stream with cipher
        copyStreams(cipherIS, output);  // copyStream is let to the implementer's choice.
    }
}
```

And I'll let you figure out how to decrypt.

EDIT :

A common way to communicate encrypted bytes without fear for encoding issues is to encode the raw bytes with base 64.

You can wrap the outputStream with `Base64.getEncoder().wrap(os)`

Comment: Will you give me a hint for the decrypting part? Do I use the OutputStream as a writer then, or is it reading the encoded part?

Comment: @MalteS assuming you've written the encrypted data in a file, the code for decryption is exactly the same, except that you need to init your cipher in decrypt mode.

Comment: So I save it as a new file, I guess? Or is it better to override it?

Comment: You can use a pair of `PipedOutputStream` (and `PipiedInputStream`) to plug the encrypted outputStream to the deciphering inputStream if you want to decrypt right away. I understand you just want to exercise a bit but there is really no meaning to encrypt and decrypt a file in a row. Encryption is pretty much always done for storage or communication. You can plug the `OutputStream` to a file or to a websocket / servlet and that will cover most of the use for encryption.

Comment: I see it is not very senseful. So to save the encrypted file seperatly can I just write the `string line;` to a file because it is printing it correctly?

Comment: You can write bytes to a file but not a String, because, as Joop and James pointed out, converting the bytes to a String is bound to destroy information as UTF-8 hasn't mapped every possible byte to distinct characters. Your encrypted data must be considered as a lump of raw bytes that cannot be decoded. The usual way to represent them as a String is to encode them using base64. Thus : clearFile --DES encrypt--> encrypted bytes --base64 encode--> printable string (store it whereever you want) -- base64 decode--> encrypted bytes --DES decrypt--> cleardata

Comment: Is the code for decryption really the same, just in DECRYPT_MODE? When I save the encrypted file it can't be decrypted like that?

Comment: The code for decryption is really the same (well, your inputFile is different), you're copying a file while passing bytes through the cipher. If the cipher is in ENCRYPT_MODE, the copied file is encrypted, if it's in DECRYPT_MODE, the copied file is decrypted.

Answer (score 2):

`FileReader/FileWriter` are the wrong (old utility) classes, as they use the current platform encoding, and a file encrypted on one computer (Greek Windows) would not be decryptable on another computer (Linux server).

Text in java, `String`, is in Unicode. One cannot (should not) throw arbitrary bytes into a String.

So the following cannot be done

```
new String(textEncrypted); // Uses the default platform encoding
new String(textEncrypted, "UTF-8"); // Probably the bytes are not valid UTF-8
```

So do:

```
Path path = Paths.get("text.txt");
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
content = encrypt(content);
Files.write(path, content);
```